# set content of Facebook post box (editable div) via javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, contenteditable, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet which when clicked inserts a specific text into the currently active text control. Don't judge.

So this is my code so far:

```
(function()
{
    var t="<<< VALUE >>>";
    var a=document.activeElement;
    if(!a) alert("No active element found.");
    if(!!a)
        if(a.nodeName=="TEXTAREA"||a.nodeName=="INPUT")
            if(!a.value) a.value=t;
            else a.value+=t;
    else if(a.nodeName=="DIV"&&a.isContentEditable==true)
        if(!a.textContent) a.textContent=t;
        else a.textContent+=t;
    }
)();
```

It works for textareas and inputs, but not for editable divs. It does change the text, but the control is broken afterwards in a way that I can't use backspace or delete anymore.

How do I set the content of such a div without braking anything?

The best place to test this is supposedly facebook. Put the focus on the text control for a new post, then execute the function. You'll notice that you can't use backspace and delete anymore.

### // EDIT

After some comments and jsfiddle experiments it looks like this is indeed a Facebook related problem. I've updated the title accordingly. Still baffles me why this is the behavior and how to overcome it.

Comment: Have you tried disabled the editable state, setting the text and then re-enabling it?

Comment: Not exactly related, but there are definitely better testing pads than FB = ). See e.g. https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Teemu It would be simpler, quicker and make a vast amount more sense to use a snippet on this site.  jsfiddle is **_not_** a good suggestion any more.

Comment: @Archer I was talking about testing in general,  I wasn't advising how to add code  to the question ...

Comment: @Teemu That's fair enough, but I assumed he was using FB as an example because that's exactly what the bookmarklet is for.

Comment: This seems to work - so perhaps FB is doing something else? https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/wpyn6tf2/

Comment: Ultimately the bookmarklet should work with a multitude of sites, but Facebook is making problems. It does indeed seem that FB handles its editable div differently, because even after using the HTML of the div in jsfiddle it still works in there. I guess there must be something on FB what changes things there. But what?